# Is it Ok to call managed code from an unmanaged shell extension?

Tags: shell, unmanaged, managed

I've read that it's unwise to implement a shell extension using managed code.

But if I go ahead and implement the shell extension using unmanaged code (C++ or Delphi), is it then ok for that unmanaged shell extension to call methods in managed (C#) assemblies? Or must the entire shell extension and everything it calls be unmanaged?

Comment: That does not solve the core problem, the issue is that another shell extension might have injected an old version of the CLR into the Explorer process.  So yours won't work.  Shell extensions need to have a minimal number of runtime dependencies to have any decent odds to run properly on another machine.

Comment: Does this limitation apply even to third party libraries like SharpShell which support shell extensions via managed code? Or do they have some special workaround?

Comment: It is programmers using SharpShell, and others, that caused this problem.  If you can be sure that this is only deployed on machines that are in your control, and can thus ensure you don't install any dated junk, then it is not a problem.